# Java error loading images from a jar

Tags: image, jar

I know there are many threads for this, but im still to silly to fix this problem..

Im loading my images by the following:

```
ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource("../" + src).toString().substring(5)));
```

I read in some threads (in german) that with this method you can load images from a jar, but also run it correct from eclipse. 
But anyway im getting this error, when trying to open the jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at game.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:17)
        at game.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:34)
        at game.GUI.main(GUI.java:115)
        ... 5 more
```

Im running this from console with:   `java -jar CastleNightmare.jar`

What im making ewrong?

Thank you!

Comment: To understand where is the error, try to break the statement in several smaller statements. I.e., create a string with the resource path, then pass it to the File constructor, then pass it to ImageIO.read. The problem is a NullPointerException; maybe getResource() returns NULL in this case?

Comment: I don't think `getResource()` supports "relative" URLs. Also note that filenames inside a .jar are *case sensitive* even when using an OS where filenames are not (like Windows or MacOS)